# Python: Binary to Base64

Tags: python, binary, base64

So I have a binary number, `001000` i.e. `8`.

If I do `base64.b64encode(001000)` I get an error.

So I do `base64.b64encode(b'001000')` and I get `b'MDAxMDAw'`.

But I need to get the base64 character in the index of the original number, `001000` or 8, which in this case would be `'I'`. Or if the number was `011100` (28), then the corresponding character on the base64 table with a value of 28 would be: `'d'`.

For example: here are some values in the b64 table

`0 == A, 1 == B, 2 == C, 3 == D, 4 == E`

So what I want to do is: First, convert the binary number to decimal `(000011 == 3)` . Then take that number and compare it to the base64 table, and you will see that `3` or `000011`, is equal to `'D'`.

Does anyone know how I could do this?

Comment: you tried `0b001000` ?

Comment: if you do `base64.b64encode(b'0b001000')` you get `b'MGIwMDEwMDA='`

Comment: or if you do `base64.b64encode(0b001000)` you get an error

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, the following should do what you want:

```
base64.b64encode(bytes([0b001000]))
```

Explanation:

- `0b001000`: the `0b` notation returns the integer 8
- `[0b001000]`: creates an array of length 1
- `bytes([0b001000])`: converts an iterable to bytes
- `b64encode(bytes([0b001000]))`: converts these bytes to base64 encoding

Comment: that returned `b'CA=='` for me, but what i was hoping for was `'I'`

Comment: if you look at a base64 table you will see the value column and character column and since the value of 'I' is 8 when i do `001000` i expected an 'I', thanks anyway

Comment: `CA==` is the base64 encoding of the byte `0001000`, right? Where does the `'I'` come from?

Comment: well,  `001000` in decimal is `8` and in the base64 table 'I' in base64  is equal to 8 in decimal right?

Comment: sorry if that is confusing

Comment: You are completely right. Now I am confused as well :-D I hope the `0b` notation helps you a little, at least.

Comment: The total input is treated as a single bitstream, then broken into blocks of 6 bits each. If the number of bits isn't a multiple of 6, additional 0 bits are appended to the stream. Further, the output is padded with `=` to make the length a multiple of 4.